# Vauxhall Corsa 3dr 1.0 active

Tags: wheels, alignment, springs

I need to replace my rear springs, do I need a wheel alignment after this? I’ve just had a wheel alignment done so hope not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are replacing your springs because they are sagging then yes, you will need an alignment because the new springs will raise the rear end. Raising the ride height will throw off the alignment, the bottom of the tires will point in towards the center of the car, what's known as positive camber. This will be bad for your tires because the outside of the tires will wear faster, and be bad for your handling (and safety) as it means less rear tire is in contact with the road. So, unfortunately you'll need to get that done, saving that money now means more money spent later and increases risk.